# AngularJS filters tests keep failing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, filter, jasmine

I have an Angular app which I need to use AngularJS filters instead of Angular Pipes (hybrid app).

So my AngularJS app is pretty much an ng module, with FilterA myModule, filterB filterBmodule, filterC filterCmodule ...

No controllers, no route, no templates - only the filters (router / views / etc. is in Angular).

The problem is that my AngularJS test cases are keep failing. 
Every time I run the tests I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr]: http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2... ...   ... ... nomod myModule. ... 
...
...
TypeError: myAfilter is not a function
```

My filters look something like:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
     angular.module('myModule')
         .filter('myFilterAtmp', aFilter);

      function aFilter( ...
```

and the spec.js file looks something like:

```
describe('My Filter ..', function () {
    var myAfilter;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('myModule');
        inject(function (myFilterAtmpFilter) {
           myAfilter = myFilterAtmpFilter;
```

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the filter constructor doesn't return a function. Hard to tell because the question doesn't show the code for the filter constructor.

Comment: So the filter works well. It's just the test cases that getting failed

Comment: Does `myModule` available within your `spec.js`?

Comment: I am having the same issue.

A simple filter (fn not incl)
`angular
        .module("demo.datetime")
        .filter("dueInMinutes", dueInMinutesFn);
`

This is the spec:
`describe('dueInMinutes', () => {
  'use strict';
 
  let $filter;

  beforeEach(() => {
    module('demo.datetime');

    inject((_$filter_) => {
      $filter = _$filter_;
    });
  });

  it('should return, () => {
    let due = $filter('dueInMinutes')(args);
    expect( due ).not.toBeNull();
   
  });

});
`
Error:
Unknown prov: dueInMinutesFilterProvider <- dueInMinutesFilter